# ¿Cómo arreglar la advertencia de File.toURL() deprecated?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando poner una ruta absoluta a un archivo .wav dentro de mi computadora para reproducirlo, pero al momento de convertirlo a URL, me arroja esta advertencia:

> The method toURL() from the type File is deprecated

El código que he implementado es:

```
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

    public class Reproductor
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            try{
                File archivo = new File("/home/josue/Descargas/song.wav");
                URL url = archivo.toURL();
                AudioClip sonido = new JApplet.newAudioClip(url);
                sonido.loop();
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e){
                System.out.println("Salio mal");
            }
        }
    }
```

**¿Cómo puede arreglar la advertencia?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El warning de desuso se debe a que `toURL()` no manipula correctamente algunos caracteres especiales, básicamente eso; Al respecto Oracle documenta [este bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6179468).

La manera de deshacerse de esa advertencia es primero convertir vía `toURI()` para luego sí hacer el paso a URL con `toURL()`, de tal forma que:

`URL url = archivo.toURI().toURL();`